issue creating Docker postgres container,
I am trying to run a Docker YAML file to host a local database to test changes for a project at work. I am running a windows 10 machine and the following connection information and configuration works well for my teammates no problems
I am running
Docker version 26.1.1, build 4cf5afa
and my docker compose is
Docker Compose version v2.27.0-desktop.2
my docker-compose.yml file is as such
version: '3.8'

services:
  insights:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      secrets:
        - secret1
        - secret2
      args:
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "chmod +x *.sh && /bin/sh -c \"/wait-for-it.sh db /docker-entrypoint.sh\""
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=local
      - 'insights-db-secrets={"db_id": "insights-db-local", "db_name": "our_db", "engine": "postgres", "host": "our_db:5432", "password": "password", "port": 5432, "username": "postgres"}'
    platform: linux/amd64
    depends_on:
      - our_db

  our_db:
    image: registry.northpole.org/registry/santashouse/postgres:16.1-alpine3.19
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=our_db
    platform: linux/amd64

volumes:
  postgres_data:

secrets:
  secret1:
    environment: secret1
  secret2:
    environment: secret2

my requirements-dev.txt file is
fastapi>=0.109.2,<0.110.0
pydantic>=2.6.1,<2.7
uvicorn>=0.27.0.post1,<0.28.0
asyncpg>=0.24.0,<0.30.0
aiohttp>=3.8.6,<3.9.5
authlib>=0.15.3,<1.2.0
async-lru>=1.0.2,<2.0.5
pydantic-settings>=0.3.0,<2.2.2
SQLAlchemy>=1.4.26,<2.0.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.9.1,<3.0.0
pytest
coverage
httpx

my requirements.txt file is
    fastapi>=0.109.2,<0.110.0
    pydantic>=2.6.1,<2.7
    uvicorn>=0.27.0.post1,<0.28.0
    asyncpg>=0.24.0,<0.30.0
    aiohttp>=3.8.6,<3.9.5
    authlib>=0.15.3,<1.2.0
    async-lru>=1.0.2,<2.0.5
    pydantic-settings>=0.3.0,<2.2.2
    SQLAlchemy>=1.4.26,<2.0.0
    psycopg2-binary>=2.9.1,<3.0.0

this works with no issues for my teammates on mac machines, but I get the following in the logs
where the postgres db seems to just be waiting in perpetuity
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
how can I get this running from my windows machine?
my Dockerfile.dev is as follows -of course anonymized, but the connections work as I pull in the python requirements
$ cat Dockerfile.dev
FROM registry.npgitlab.opr.northpole.org/registry/elfcommunity/np-common-files:2.0.0 as common-files
FROM registry.npgitlab.opr.northpole.org/registry/elfcommon/python/3.12:alpine3.17 AS python-base

LABEL "MAINTAINER" "Naughty List<SANTAS-LIST9@internal.northpole.com>"
LABEL "Project" "Naughty List"

ARG JFROG_HOST=packages.ic1.northpole

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

COPY --from=common-files /ssl/nppki.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY --from=common-files /scripts /opt/np_scripts/

RUN \
   --mount=type=secret,id=apk_http_auth \
   source /run/secrets/apk_http_auth \
   && cat /opt/cst/nptrust.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
   && /opt/np_scripts/setup_apk_repos.sh packages.ic1.northpole\
   && apk update && apk upgrade \
   && apk add --no-cache postgresql-client \
   && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN \
   --mount=type=secret,id=pip_conf \
   . /run/secrets/pip_conf \
   && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
   && pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY /scripts/. /

WORKDIR /
COPY . /

EXPOSE 80

RUN chmod +x *.sh

docker ps shows this
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                            COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
d90804573d9d   registry.npgitlab.opr.northpole.org/registry/santashouse/postgres:16.1-alpine3.19   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   insights-insightsdb-1


Is the container for the insights service running? Run docker ps to check. It would be helpful to see the Dockerfile.dev used for that service too.

I just added that to the submission. Thanks

Based on the docker ps output it looks like the insights service isn't running.
An observation: the last line of your Dockerfile.dev, RUN chmod +x *.sh, is duplicated in the entrypoint listed in docker-compose.yml.
This will likely not solve the problem, but will simplify your setup slightly: remove the entrypoint from docker-compose.yml and put this at the end of your Dockerfile:
RUN chmod +x *.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-it.sh", "db", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

I have not used wait-for-it.sh, but looking at the documentation I think that you might need to tweak the command a bit. Perhaps something like this might work better:
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-it.sh", "our_db:5432", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]


Specify the name of the database service (our_bd) and its port.
The command that you want to run after the service is up appears to need to follow after --.


Thanks for the info - it did both things you mentioned : cleared up some redundant code and cleaned up the pipeline - but it did not resolve the issue. I am meeting with a containerization SME today. Thanks for replying
